# Unexpected token while compiling ejs i18next

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs, i18next

I am getting the error `Unexpected token ) while compiling ejs` when doing translation using i18next.

I have implemented the translation using i18next, below is the following code, getting the following error when using map function

```
en.json

{
  "title": "List of Countries",
  "list":[{
     "name": "Singapore",
     "code": "SG"
  },{
    "name": "Thailand",
    "code": "TH"
 }]
}

index.ejs 
  <h4><%=t('title')%></h4> //outputs correctly
  <ul>
      <%=t('list').map(e=>{%>
          <li><%=e.name%></li>
      <%})%>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ejs scripts are incorrect when iterating over the array, you need to remove the assign character when iterating and use the object "e" instead of "li" as follows:

```
<ul> 
<%_ t('list').map(e=>{-%> 
<li><%=e.name%></li>
<%_  }) -%>
</ul>
```

Use:

"<%_" to remove previous whitespaces when rendering the ejs

"-%>" to remove the line

See [official ejs docs](https://ejs.co/#docs) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the assign character and you are ok.

```
<ul>
    <% t.list.map(e => {%>
       <li><%=e.name%></li>
    <%})%>
</ul>
```